# JSON undefined property - simplified validation to avoid TypeErrors

Tags: javascript, json, properties, undefined, simplify

I am attempting to efficiently validate multi-layered json objects which may have one or more undefined parent properties depending on the scenario.

This is an example of and object just 2 levels of properties:

```
scenarioArray = [ 
{color:{blue:'yes'}},
{color:{green:'no'}},
{colour:{blue:'yes'}} ]; //colour instead of color
```

So I want to most efficiently identify a scenario's color

```
let color;
let s = randomScenario; //random scenario from the scenarioArray
if(s.color != undefined && s.color.blue != undefined) {
    color = s.color.blue;
} else if (s.color != undefined && s.color.green != undefined) {
    color = s.color.green;
} else if (s.colour != undefined && s.colour.blue !=undefined) {
    color = s.colour.blue;
};
```

This code technically works, it is just messy.

When you extrapolate this into objects with 4-5 levels of properties, the if statements become unwieldy and unreadable.

I would love suggestions on how to simply this.

real world json object examples:

```
addendum.contract.buyerInformation.name 
addendum.contract.contract.buyerInformation.name
addendum.contract.purchaser.buyerFirstName
addendum.contract.data.purchaser.buyer.name
```

frameworks/libraries used: 
AngularJS
Lodash
(open to any suggested libraries that could make this more efficient too)

P.S. please let me know if this is too open ended of a question for stackOverflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, JavaScript lacks native [autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/autovivification), but it can be emulated via [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to some degree.

This is an awkward and brittle solution, but it reduces any-deep-check to two actions and should work for most cases:

```js
'use strict';

const isEmpty = Symbol('isEmpty');

function autoVivify(object = {}) {
  Object.defineProperty(object, isEmpty, {
    get: () => Object.keys(object).length === 0,
  });

  Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
    const val = object[key];
    if (typeof val === 'object' && val !== null) object[key] = autoVivify(val);
  });

  return new Proxy(
    object,
    { get: (obj, name) => name in obj ? obj[name] : obj[name] = autoVivify() },
  );
}

const scenarioArray = [
    { color: { blue: 'yes' }},
    { color: { green: 'no' }},
    { colour: { blue: 'yes' }},
];

const randomScenario = autoVivify(scenarioArray[0]);

if (randomScenario.color.blue && !randomScenario.color.blue[isEmpty])
  console.log(randomScenario.color.blue);

if (randomScenario.color.red && !randomScenario.color.red[isEmpty])
  console.log(randomScenario.color.red);

if (randomScenario.color.a.b.c && !randomScenario.color.a.b.c[isEmpty])
  console.log(randomScenario.color.a.b.c);

if (randomScenario.colour.green && !randomScenario.colour.green[isEmpty])
  console.log(randomScenario.colour.blue);
```

Let's hope we will have [a more appropriate way](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which can find errors for u. It supports up to three levels. it's configurable. for 4th and 5th levels you can extend it or make it recursive for unlimited levels support:

```js
const validSecondLevels = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
const validThirdLevels = ['yes', 'no']
const validPropertyNames = ['color']


scenarioArray = [
    { color: { bluee: 'yes' } },
    { color: { green: 'invalid-value' } },
    { colour: { blue: 'yes' } }];

function findErrors(scenario) {
    var invalidProperties = scenarioArray.filter(function (it) {

        var invalidPropertyNames = Object.keys(it).filter(item => !validPropertyNames.includes(item));

        if (invalidPropertyNames.length)
            return it;

        var foundProperties = validPropertyNames.filter(item => it[item]).map(item => it[item]);

        var invalids = foundProperties.filter(function (property) {

            var invalidSecondLevels = Object.keys(property).filter(item => !validSecondLevels.includes(item));

            if (invalidSecondLevels.length)
                return property;

            var foundValues = validSecondLevels.filter(item => property[item]).map(item => property[item]);

            var invalidThirdLevels = foundValues.filter(function (foundValue) {
                return !validThirdLevels.includes(foundValue);
            });

            if (invalidThirdLevels.length)
                return property;

        });

        if (invalids.length)
            return it;

    });

    return invalidProperties;
}

console.log(findErrors(scenarioArray));
```